# Query to get data from 3 different table for different keys

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, sqlite

I've three different table and want to get data from it.
if any one have some solution for it please help me out.

### user table

```
userName | email(p.k) | accountType(p.k)

 Vivek    | v@asd.asd | google

Rahul    | r@asd.asd | facebook
```

### event table

```
eventId(p.k) | email(f.k) | accountType(f.k) | eventName

1    | v@asd.asd | google | birthday
```

### contributer

```
eventId(f.k) | email(f.k) | accountType(f.k) | contribute

1    | r@asd.asd | facebook | $20
```

I want the data like

`Rahul contribute $20 for vivek birthday`

How to fetch rahul and vivek in single query can any one help me out

Comment: use join over the fk and join  user table once with contributer and  once with Event table. you have to user table twice

Comment: You have accepted an answer, so thanks for that. There is no need to edit your question to include that solution. In fact please don't do that, it just muddies things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query should be pretty straightforward, we just need to join to the user table twice.

```
SELECT * 
FROM user
JOIN contribute ON user.email = contribute.email
JOIN event ON event.id = contribute._eventId
JOIN user u2 ON event.email = u2.email;
```

Comment: for getting user name twice we need to use *as* either we get only one username

Comment: You are correct; you will want to use aliases where the columns have the same name.

Comment: if i want to count the no of contribute for an event in the same query. how can we do that

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*) as eventCount, u2.userName as u2Name, ....` then append a `GROUP BY event._eventId` to the end of the query.

Comment: if i use group by i can't see multiple records for the same event

Comment: Misread, hopefully, all of your tables have a primary key, ID field. `GROUP BY contribute.id` might get what you want. If that's not good enough, then you either want to do the counts in a separate query or JOIN on a sub table which has the counts in it. For example something like `JOIN (SELECT contribute.id, count(*) as contributeCount FROM ....... rest of query ...... GROUP BY contribute.id) countTable ON contribute.id = countTable.id`. We are starting to get further away from the original question functionally. Maybe open a new question once you've researched and tried a few ideas